# Autocomplete in Texmaker works weirdly

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

I'm using Texmaker 4.5 and I'm experiencing strange behaviour of the autocompletion. If I type "\beg" it automatically jumps to \begin{o} and I can start typing within the brackets, and get another autocompletion-suggestion according to what I type. But when I type "\cit" I'm getting the first suggestion of \citep{Author1YearX} instead of \cite{o}, where I could start typing an author again, but this option is at the very end of the list, which is annoying. It's the same in the case of "\ref" where the first reference is the first element in the list instead of "\ref{o}".
Is there any workaround or other solution to fix this?

Comment: As a workaround, I now defined User-Tags that give \cite{@} by pressing shift+F1 and \ref{@} by pressing shift+F2 which decreases the time I need to type the correct citation or reference. Anyway, this doesn't solve the initial problem.